Quiero agregar << 1 2 3 4 5 >> en mi data table en vez de previous 1 2 3 4 5 next
Necesito ayuda para poner esos números y también que cada linea intercale de oscuro a gris
o si eso saber donde esta los códigos de cada uno de ellos para buscarlo mas fácilmente
me harian un gran favor
script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.5/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.5/js/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var table; 

$(document).ready(function() {
    
    table = $('#tablaClientes').DataTable({
        "paging": true,      
        "searching": true,  
        "info": true,         
        "responsive": true     
    });
});


No entiendo tu pregunta: "Colocar 1,2,3,4 en la data table, en vez de previous 1,2,3,4". Intenta agregar un ejemplo de salid esperada y salida obtenida

Aparentemente quiere cambiar "previous" por "<<<" y "Next" por ">>>", pero creo que le falta poner un poco más de información del problema ...

@Jakala Ha, ya. Se puede hacer con un remplace o con expresiones regulares.

Para que te salgan las filas alternadamente oscuras y claras, agrega la clase stripe a tu elemento '#tablaClientes'

Basta con mirar la documentación: language.

Esta respuesta también está en parte relacionada.

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Si solo quieres modificar la cadena se puede hacer fácilmente con replace, y de paso también se puede usar expresiones regulares:
Solo replace:


const string_example="previous 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 22.... 231 next";
let new_string=string_example.replace("previous","<<<").replace("next",">>>");
console.log(`Cadena original: ${string_example}`);
console.log(`Cadena modificado: ${new_string}`);



Para más control podemos usar expresiones regulares:


const search_=/(?:previous)([0-9\s]+)next/g,
  string_example="previous 1 2 3 4 5 6 next";

let new_string=string_example.replace(search_,"<<<$1>>>");
console.log(new_string);




(?:previous): Buscar algo que comience en "previous".
([0-9\s]): Busca número y espacios en blanco (el "()" es para marcar un grupo).
next: Termina en...

